# Git Hook post-receive not executing

Tags: git, gitlab, git-post-receive

--Git hook newbie --

Post-receive not executing when pushed to a git hosted in git lab.

The git repo in our live server is a clone of the gitlab repo.

Why does when i push to the gitlab repo, the git in the live server does not execute the post-receive in the hooks.

Do i need something to set up in the gitlab?

The post-receive is in the live server .git/hooks/post-receive but not on the local and is not pushed in the gitlab repo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [official guide](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/administration/custom_hooks.html) indicates, you do not have to install hooks in 
`.git/hooks/post-receive`, but in `/home/git/repositories/<group>/<project>.git/custom_hooks/` (if installed by sources) or in `/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/<group>/<project>.git/custom_hooks/` if installed by Omnibus